# How to fix 'After updating text in QLabel, text randomly changes between new and old value'

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside2

I'm using two threads `Camera` and `NetworkProcessor` in Qt application, which displayes their actual state in QLabel (there is one label for each thread: `camStatusLabel`, `nnStatusLabel`). To update text in label I am using signals and slots. There is also 6 labels to display images, which are updated in while loop periodically (`cameraView`, `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, `k4`, `k5`) with  signals and slots as well.

```py
import cv2
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
import threading as th

from PIL import Image
import copy

class SecondPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.bigSize = QSize(640, 480)
        self.smallSize = QSize(320, 240)

        blackPic = QPixmap(self.bigSize)
        blackPic.fill(Qt.black)

        self.layoutTop = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layoutTop.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.topRowLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.buttonBack = QPushButton("Back")
        self.camStatusLabel = QLabel("Camera status: not running...")
        self.nnStatusLabel = QLabel("Neural net status: not running...")
        self.topRowLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBack, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
        self.topRowLayout.addWidget(self.camStatusLabel, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.topRowLayout.addWidget(self.nnStatusLabel, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.cameraView = QLabel()
        self.cameraView.setFixedSize(self.bigSize)
        self.cameraView.setPixmap(blackPic)

        self.knnLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.layoutTop.addLayout(self.topRowLayout, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.layoutTop.addWidget(self.cameraView, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layoutTop.addLayout(self.knnLayout, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.k1 = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.k1.setFixedSize(self.smallSize)
        self.k1.setPixmap(blackPic)
        self.k2 = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.k2.setFixedSize(self.smallSize)
        self.k2.setPixmap(blackPic)
        self.k3 = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.k3.setFixedSize(self.smallSize)
        self.k3.setPixmap(blackPic)
        self.k4 = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.k4.setFixedSize(self.smallSize)
        self.k4.setPixmap(blackPic)
        self.k5 = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.k5.setFixedSize(self.smallSize)
        self.k5.setPixmap(blackPic)

        self.knnLayout.addWidget(self.k1)
        self.knnLayout.addWidget(self.k2)
        self.knnLayout.addWidget(self.k3)
        self.knnLayout.addWidget(self.k4)
        self.knnLayout.addWidget(self.k5)

        self.setLayout(self.layoutTop)

        self.frame = [None]
        self.frameLock = QMutex()

        startExecute = th.Event()
        threadIsLoadedEvent = th.Event()

        self.cameraThread = Camera()
        self.connect(self.cameraThread, SIGNAL("updateCameraView(QImage)"), self.updateCameraView)
        self.connect(self.cameraThread, SIGNAL("updateCameraStatus(QString)"), self.updateCameraStatus)
        self.cameraThread.startCapturing(self.frame, self.frameLock, startExecute, threadIsLoadedEvent)

        self.processingThread = NetworkProcessor()
        self.connect(self.processingThread, SIGNAL("updateResults(QImage,QImage,QImage,QImage,QImage)"), self.updateResults)
        self.connect(self.processingThread, SIGNAL("nnStatusLabel(QString)"), self.updateNNStatus)
        self.processingThread.startAnalyzing(self.frame, self.frameLock, self.smallSize.toTuple(), startExecute, threadIsLoadedEvent)

        startExecute.set()


    def updateCameraStatus(self, text):
        self.camStatusLabel.setText(text)
        self.camStatusLabel.update()

    def updateNNStatus(self, text):
        self.nnStatusLabel.setText(text)
        self.nnStatusLabel.update()

    def updateCameraView(self, image):
        self.cameraView.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image).scaled(self.bigSize))
        self.cameraView.update()

    def updateResults(self, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5):
        self.k1.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(p1))
        self.k1.update()

        self.k2.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(p2))
        self.k2.update()

        self.k3.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(p3))
        self.k3.update()

        self.k4.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(p4))
        self.k4.update()

        self.k5.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(p5))
        self.k5.update()

    def killPage(self):
        self.cameraThread.stopThread()
        self.processingThread.stopThread()

class Camera(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exit = False
        self.frame = None
        self.frameLock = None
        self.initSuccessEvent = None
        self.startEvent = None

    def stopThread(self):
        self.exit = True
        self.wait()

    def startCapturing(self, frame, frameLock, startEvent, initSuccessEvent):
        self.frame = frame
        self.frameLock = frameLock
        self.initSuccessEvent = initSuccessEvent
        self.startEvent = startEvent
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self.startEvent.wait()

        self.emit(SIGNAL("updateCameraStatus(QString)"), "Camera status: Opening...")
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)

        #initialize frame and signal success to main thead
        self.frameLock.lock()
        _, self.frame[0] = cap.read()
        self.frameLock.unlock()
        self.initSuccessEvent.set()

        self.emit(SIGNAL("updateCameraStatus(QString)"), "Camera status: Running...")

        #enter into loop
        while True:
            _, img = cap.read()
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

            self.frameLock.lock()
            self.frame[0] = copy.deepcopy(img)
            self.frameLock.unlock()

            img = QImage(img, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], img.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.emit(SIGNAL("updateCameraView(QImage)"), img)

            if self.exit:
                cap.release()
                break

class NetworkProcessor(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exit = False
        self.frame = None
        self.frameLock = None
        self.imgSize = (100,100)
        self.initSuccessEvent = None
        self.startEvent = None

    def stopThread(self):
        self.exit = True
        self.wait()

    def startAnalyzing(self, frame, frameLock, imgSize, startEvent, initSuccessEvent):
        self.frame = frame
        self.frameLock = frameLock
        self.imgSize = imgSize
        self.initSuccessEvent = initSuccessEvent
        self.startEvent = startEvent
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        import pydevd;pydevd.settrace(suspend=False)
        self.startEvent.wait()
        self.emit(SIGNAL("nnStatusLabel(QString)"), "Neural net status: Waiting for camera...")
        self.initSuccessEvent.wait()

        self.emit(SIGNAL("nnStatusLabel(QString)"), "Neural net status: Loading nn and dataset...")

        QThread.msleep(1000) #to simulate initialization

        self.emit(SIGNAL("nnStatusLabel(QString)"), "Neural net status: Running...")

        while True:
            QThread.msleep(1000)

            if self.exit:
                break

            self.frameLock.lock()
            camImg = copy.deepcopy(self.frame[0])
            self.frameLock.unlock()

            products = self._processImg(Image.fromarray(camImg), 5)

            data1 = products[0].tobytes('raw', 'RGB')
            k1 = QImage(data1, products[0].size[0], products[0].size[1], QImage.Format_RGB888)

            data2 = products[1].tobytes('raw', 'RGB')
            k2 = QImage(data2, products[1].size[0], products[1].size[1], QImage.Format_RGB888)

            data3 = products[2].tobytes('raw', 'RGB')
            k3 = QImage(data3, products[2].size[0], products[2].size[1], QImage.Format_RGB888)

            data4 = products[3].tobytes('raw', 'RGB')
            k4 = QImage(data4, products[3].size[0], products[3].size[1], QImage.Format_RGB888)

            data5 = products[4].tobytes('raw', 'RGB')
            k5 = QImage(data5, products[4].size[0], products[4].size[1], QImage.Format_RGB888)

            self.emit(SIGNAL("updateResults(QImage,QImage,QImage,QImage,QImage)"), k1, k2, k3, k4, k5)

            if self.exit:
                break

    def _processImg(self, queryImg, k):
        imgs = []
        for i in range(k):
            im = queryImg.rotate(20*i)
            im = im.resize(self.imgSize)
            imgs.append(im)

        return imgs

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.loadSecondPage()


    def loadSecondPage(self):
        widget = SecondPage()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Metriclearning demo - Visualisation")

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("Closing app")
        self.centralWidget().killPage()
        event.accept()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that, when I am updating text labels containing thread state (`camStatusLabel`, `nnStatusLabel`), the content does not remain as I have set it, but randomly changes to previous texts and back, even though the text is not updated never again once the thread enters into `while` loop.

The same problem is observable on labels containing images.

Does anyone know what might cause this problem?

EDIT:
I eddited the code above to be executable. The problem is same as I have already described: The text in QLabel `nnStatusLabel` changes even though it is not supposed to and similar behavior is occasionally observable on displayed images as well - displayed images returns back in time (`cameraView`, `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, `k4`, `k5`).

Comment: I've tested your code, I can't manage to reproduce the behavior you see... Everything seems to work fine here.

Comment: So, when you run the code there is 'Neural net status: Running...' in top right label all the time since thread  NetworkProcessor enters while loop? If so might it be bug in particular version of PySide2? What version are you using? I have PySide2 v5.13.0 installed by pip